# UK Standard Visitor visa (visit - family - 6 months ) - For wife and child - Indian Citizens

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen living in India. I plan to send my wife and child to the UK to visit my cousin. They will be staying with my cousin and also doing some sightseeing. The visit will be for 15 days. My wife is a housewife and my child is 14 years old.

I have few questions regarding "Employment and Income" for both my wife and child.

- **For my wife**

1) for **Total Monthly Income From** can I add

a) Savings and Investments    and
  b) Other sources including friends and family

for my wife. Savings and Investments are from the fixed deposits which are held in joint mode. And the other sources are source of income which we get from rented property.

2) for **Is someone other than you paying for all or a part of your trip?** do I need to mention "Yes" or "No"?

If it is a "Yes" what should I enter for **Please explain why they are paying towards the cost of your trip?**

- **For my child**

1) For **The total amount of money you have for this trip** , should I put it as 0 or NONE as I will be sponsoring the trip for my child?

2) For **Please explain why they are paying towards the cost of your trip?**, what should be the standard and acceptable answer

In addition to this

1) Does my wife need to take the papers related to property and savings while going for the interview?

Comment: Do you *seriously* not know why you are paying towards your wife and child's visit?

Comment: @GayotFow - Thanks for responding. I am paying for their visit as they are my family. But would this be an acceptable answer?

Comment: Yes, but honestly, forget about trying to isolate the 'acceptable' answers. Use natural language and tell the truth. Something like "I have supported my wife for 12 years and this occasion is no different."  If you search the net for 'acceptable' answers, your application will not flow and they will pick up on it.

Comment: Trying to find 'acceptable' answers will invariably risk backfiring. It's a silly thing to do anyway.